# Result from radio button test doesn't inserts into database,whats wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, radio-button

sorry for simple questions but i tried it too long and cant do this.

> So the question is this : I have test with three radio options ,and
>   for each option being pressed i want that option to increase on 1 or
>   whatever number i want and then add the count of each radio button
>   being pressed to the database ??? I have a mysql table named 'test '
>   with three elements : 'gr' - varchar - 255 - utf8general_ci, 're' -
>   int - 10 , 'ye' - int - 10 . So When someones press for example radio
>   button with value green , i want that 'gr' in my sql table 'test '
>   increase on 1.

PHP Code:

```
<?php

$a=mysql_connect('xxxx','xxxx','xxxx');

$b=mysql_select_db('xxxx',$a);

$red=1;
$green=1;
$yellow=1;

if ($_POST){


if ($_POST['color']=='green'){

$green+=1;

$query='UPDATE test SET gr='.$green.'';

mysql_query($query);

 }

 if ($_POST['color']=='red'){

 $red+=1;

$query='UPDATE test SET re='.$red.'';

mysql_query($query);

 }

 if ($_POST['color']=='yellow'){

$yellow+=1;


$query='UPDATE test SET ye='.$yellow.'';

mysql_query($query);

 }

 }

?>
```

Here is my html code:

```
<form action="indexni.php" method="POST ">
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="green" />Green<br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="red" />Red<br>
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="yellow" />Yellow<br>
    <input type ="submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: But still I don't see any question here.

Comment: The result doesnt inserts into database ???

Comment: You need to check for errors, something you're not doing. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: @Dreamjunior that's not a question. It's fact :) Try to debug your script and show us some error messages if you found any.

Answer (score 1):

But you are setting those $red, $green, $blue counter to 1 every time?! That way every time you start again from 1. You should just increase current value:

```
$query='UPDATE test SET ye=ye+1';
```

But if you don't have different table for every color....and I hope you don't...then you have to distinct somehow rows..... You need WHERE condition.

How your table structure looks like anyway?

Let's say you have table `test` with fields `color` and `clicks` and let's say you have 3 rows of that table where `color` field has values (per row) `red`, `green`, `yellow`.
In that case you can have mySql query that will increase color counter like this:

```
$query='UPDATE test SET clicks = clicks+1 WHERE color = "yellow"';
```

Something like that.

Comment: I have table test with three fields gr ,re ye  which logically stands for green red yellow, and when someones presses the radio button =''green" i want field gr in y database increase on 1 ???

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is 'space'. See on this `method="POST "`. Change on this `method="POST"` and it is work for you.

Comment: You array $_POST is empty. Because, `method="POST "` is mistake and your data send from GET method.

Comment: Good catch, but a partial answer. Used with MilanG's answer, OP stands at getting a full solution.

Comment: @Dreamjunior find answer 'why not input data?' I answer :) But, i know his code and logic very bad... I think he is beginner.